# Prove $S^c$ is not closed under addition.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Let $S$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $S \not = \emptyset$ and $S \not = \mathbb{R}$. Define $S^c =\{x\in \mathbb{R}:x \not \in S\}$. Suppose that $S$ is closed under addition AND closed under the additive inverse. Prove $S^c$ is not closed under addition. Find an example where $S$ and $S^c$ are both closed under multiplication.

Can someone help me with this? I do not know what to do for this, I do not even know where to start. I was given a warm-up that is supposed to help that is to prove the result for $S = \mathbb{Q}$ (so that $S^c$ is the set of irrational numbers), but I do not even know how to do this. Can someone offer me some guidance, please?

Comment: For $S=\Bbb Q$, then $S$ is closed under addition. However, $\pi +(-\pi)$ shows that $S^c$ is not.

Comment: As for an example of $S$ and $S^c$ both being closed under multiplication, $S=\{0\}$ works doesn't it?

Comment: For proving $S^c$ is not closed under addition, how would that work since $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and the set of real numbers are closed under addition?

Comment: @iSuckAtMath show that there exist $x, y\in S^c$ such that $x+y\notin S^c$.

Comment: @79037662 but if $S^c = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: x \not \in S\}$, doesn't that mean essentially that $S^c$ is the set of real numbers, which in that case any two numbers you add would be in $S^c$?

Comment: @iSuckAtMath No, $S^c$ is not the set of real numbers. In words, that definition would be "the set of real numbers which are not an element of $S$". When the definition says $x\notin S$ that means "such that $x$ is not in $S$".

Comment: @79037662 Oh ok, but S is the subset of \mathbb{R} such that $S \not = \emptyset$ and $S \not = \mathbb{R}$, so what would be in the set $S$ if S is not the empty set, and $S$ is the subset of real numbers and $S$ is not equal to real numbers?

Comment: $S$ is not *the* such subset, it's *a* such subset. Meaning, it could be *any* subset of $\mathbb{R}$ other than $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb{Q} \ni 2 = \sqrt{2} + (2 - \sqrt{2}) \in (\Bbb{R} \smallsetminus \Bbb{Q}) + (\Bbb{R} \smallsetminus \Bbb{Q})$.  In fact any $s \in S$ can be written as $c + (s - c)$ for any $c \in S^c$, for which $s - c \in S^c$ (since $S$ is closed under addition).

Comment: Why $s-c$ is not in $S$ ? $S$ is closed under addition only, does it imply $S$ is closed under subtraction also ?

Comment: $S$ need not be closed under subtraction.  For instance, $S$ could be the positive integers.  And yet, for any $c \in S^c$, $s - c \not\in S$.

Comment: Without taking example can you prove it ?